# How to read all columns of a text file, except the last one in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file in .csv format containing the following information

> 2034.5,2047.0,2018.5,1994.75,2020.75,2053.75,09/01/2015
>   2023.75,2018.5,1994.75,2020.75,2053.75,2034.5,12/01/2015
>   2019.0,1994.75,2020.75,2053.75,2034.5,2023.75,13/01/2015
>   2010.25,2020.75,2053.75,2034.5,2023.75,2019.0,14/01/2015

However, the last column (a date) is useless to me and I would like to suppress it from the final matrix created after reading the file. I need my matrix to be numerical only (with values from the first to the fifth column). I need to normalize the values in the matrix so the date value is useless.

How can I do it with Matlab?

Comment: @Arthur the xlsread solution is not working: train-1.csv. File is not in
recognized format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
fileID = fopen('q57092669_text.txt');
data = cell2mat(textscan(fileID,'%f%f%f%f%f%f%*s','Delimiter',','));
fclose(fileID);
```

Using [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html):

```
myTable = readtable('q57092669_text.txt','Format','%f%f%f%f%f%f%*s');
data = table2array(myTable);
```

Using [readmatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html), introduced in R2019a:

```
data = readmatrix('q57092669_text.txt','ExpectedNumVariables',6)
```

---

Contents of text file *q57092669_text.txt*:

```
2034.5,2047.0,2018.5,1994.75,2020.75,2053.75,09/01/2015
2023.75,2018.5,1994.75,2020.75,2053.75,2034.5,12/01/2015
2019.0,1994.75,2020.75,2053.75,2034.5,2023.75,13/01/2015
2010.25,2020.75,2053.75,2034.5,2023.75,2019.0,14/01/2015
```